# no Maps ID in the option list when Register a new identifier for apple mapkit js

Tags: identifier, mapkit-js

I am flowing [this artical](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkitjs/creating_a_maps_identifier_and_a_private_key#3011340) to enable apple map in my android app. It's very confuse me when i Create a Maps ID, the Maps ID option is missing from the option list [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/825kw.png).

I am trying to google this problem but no result. Does any one know the reason and what can i do?